# Custom Windows 7 environment variable not working

Tags: windows-7, batch-file, environment-variables

I created a new environment variable via Windows 7 advanced system settings:

```
VAR_MYPATH = "D:\someFolder"
```

I added the new variable to the path in the same dialog:

```
PATH = ...;%VAR_MYPATH%
```

When I run a new command prompt and type "CD %VAR_PATH%", no error is returned, but the command prompt does not change to "D:\someFolder".

If I attempt to launch a batch file under that folder from my C drive I end up with an error:

```
c:> %VAR_MYPATH%\someSubfolder\theBatchFile.bat
The system cannot find the path specified
```

All the paths are correct, so what am I missing to get the environment variable to work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. For compatibility reasons with MS-DOS and `COMMAND.COM`, the Windows `cmd.exe` shell maintains a *list* of "current directories", one for each drive letter, and the `cd` command changes the directory, but not the current drive.

   Use **`cd /d %var_mypath%`** to also change the current drive.
2. Do not put quotation marks in the variable value. If you do, then `%VAR_MYPATH%\someSubfolder\theBatchFile.bat` will expand to `"d:\someFolder"\someSubfolder\theBatchFile.bat`, which may confuse things. (Again, for compatibility, `cmd.exe` inherits many quirks from `COMMAND.COM`, including a strange quoted text parser.)
3. Make sure the variable actually *exists* in your current `cmd.exe` window, either by running `set var_mypath` or `echo %var_mypath%`. (Each process inherits environment from its parent.)

Comment: Thank-you for the prompt response.  I confirmed that the variable exists and there are no quotations.  Your suggestion for #2 worked.  I still cannot launch the batch file from the C drive though.  Any ideas.

Comment: @TERACytE: Is the batch file in C: or D:?

Comment: On D: (d:\someFolder\someSubfolder\theBatchFile.bat).  I want to run it from anywhere though (e.g. c:).

Comment: @TERACytE: Do `echo %VAR_MYPATH%
\someSubfolder
\theBatchFile.bat` and `dir %VAR_MYPATH%
\someSubfolder
\theBatchFile.bat` show the correct file? Does the path have spaces in it? Are you sure the error isn't actually displayed by the batch file itself? Try commenting out any `echo off` statements to see.

Comment: I got it!  There was a space just before the last slash in the path.  Thank-you for your help.